# Lispworks editor color coding

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, lispworks

Does anyone know how to maintain the color coding in the Lispworks editor?
(LispWorks Personal Edition v6.1)

It works great when entering new code.  But after saving and loading again, everything is monochrome black.

There is a checkbox under:

```
Tools > Preferences 
      > Environment
      > Styles 
      > Color parenthesis
```

But it does not affect it.

There's a workaround by loading and then copy/pasting the code into a fresh editor window and using `save-as`... but there's no way that should be required.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Lispworks editor, but I believe it's an Emacs-like editor. Is the mode set correctly for the file when you open it? I would assume that it sets it for `.lisp`/`.lsp`/`.asd` files automatically, but you might have to add something to your initialization file for other extensions (there's probably an equivalent of Emacs `auto-mode-alist` variable).

Comment: Without owning LispWorks myself (so perhaps this is a stupid question), can I ask you to clarify whether by “colour coding” you are talking about colouring certain keywords (eg `let`, `defun`, ...), or perhaps other words, or are you talking about colouring parentheses to make them match up?

Comment: Both.  It changes the color of keywords, and also assigned rotating colors to pairs of parenthesis.  I've tried saving the files in each of the available formats in the drop down in the save window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost certainly you are saving your files with an extension which the LW editor does not know means they are Lisp files.  Call them `<something>.lisp` in the standard way and all will be fine.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  For some reason the default is to save a file with no extension at all, even if *.lisp is selected in the drop down.  Typing it in worked.